# Monero GUI Wallet still synching

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, xmr.to

I have installed Monero GUI Wallet on an SSD drive. The application still shows that it's syncing after overnight. Also the data.mdb is growing past 67GBs.

It is my first time using XMR coins and I have transfered less than £40 worth of coins from https://tradeogre.com/, which confirms it is Successful. But still see 0 balance.

Below is a current snippet of the monerod.exe:

[image]

I accepted the default Blockchain Height which I have no idea what that means, all I simply want is to send XMR to my wallet.

Any advise if I am doing this all wrong or?

Much appreciated!

Edit
I have re-installed to the newest version of Wallet. Below is a snippet of the status:

[image]

The data.mdb file is now?

Comment: You are using an outdated version of the GUI. Please update to GUI v0.17.1.9: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/kt1xgp/cli_gui_v01719_oxygen_orion_released_includes/

Comment: @dEBRUYNE Thanks for the response. I downloaded and installed the v0.17.1.9 version now. It has now continued from updating the data.mdb, 69*GBs. Do I still allow the file to keep growing?

Comment: Yes, the file is current approximately 100 GB.

Comment: OK thanks, I will then need to move the bitmonero folder with the imdb sub-folder and it's contents then. And then open wallet and change the location to point to it. I will update once I get that far. Appreciate your advice

Comment: It is now going over 105 GBs. When does it show my balance? This is on an SSD. Other posts confirm it never goes more than 10GB...not 105GB. Is this normal in 2021?

Comment: On Monero Gui Wallet, in the Recieve section, it still says "Waiting on daemon synchronization to finish". I will edit post to show a snippet

Comment: Can you go to the `Settings` page -> `Log` tab, type `status`, and post the output here?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. It eventually sycned up towards 108GB file. And now it is synced up. Wasn't too sure if it was supposed to be this big. But looks all good now. Thanks again